# How to call af:popup from another page?

Tags: jsf, popup, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have used af:popup a lot in my application and I call the popup only from the pages in which it is created. For example, if popup1 is created in Page1, I can call it only from this page!

I want to call a popup being created within Page1 from Page2. The real scenario is that I want to create the popup within the pageTemplate, and use it everywhere.

The problem with this is that it does not recognize the bindings that are used in the popup when called from another page. Does anyone know how to fix or avoid this?
Please tell me what approach have you used in this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually 1 Page Definition (Binding Container) per page is not a hard/fixed restriction. You can use the **same** PageDef for more than one page. Admittedly unusual but works. Go to the Databindings.cpx file. You will notice that the jspx page is associated with its pagedef file, not by tightly coupled/direct reference, but by an indirect UsageID. Edit the metadata to have page1 and page2 use the same page definition file, via the usageID. Then the binding container will be shared by both pages.

BUT, PageTemplates can have their own page bindings - have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I know about PageTemplates bindings, but the problem is that when I am at a certain page, the bindings of the template are not recognized, they are considered as bindings of another page. However I will try the first choice of using the same pagedef file for all pages.

Comment: your answer helped me to find the an approach for the solution. I changed every usageID of each component within popup form to smth like: #{data.OtherPageDef.Title.inputValue}, I changed CreateInsert, Commit, Rollback bindings too. Now it is fine :) Thank you!

Comment: Great tip, Joe! I didn't know about this. I'm sure it'll be useful some day.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you're having is the popup when used on Page2 isn't recognizing the bindings from Page1 it's because you don't have those bindings on Page2. Check your Page2 bindings, and ensure you've got the same ones (need to be named the same as well). You will need to add them if they aren't there! Each page has its own set of bindings.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I am conscious about this but it is still a little strange.. Did you ever faced this issue? If you did please tell me what should I do. I used boundet-task-flows as popup-s and in that fixed the first issue but unexpectedly IE shows 404 on that type of popup..